# Debugging layout script

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've the following super simple Zend Application:

Controller (IndexController.php):

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $this->view->var_controller = "foo";
}
```

Layout (layout.phtml):

```
<?php 
  $var_layout;
  echo $this->var_controller; ?> (1.)
```

When i set the breakpoint at echo output in layout script ("echo $this->var_controller") the breakpint is hit 2 times!

Does it mean the layuot script is executed 2 times or there is other explanation?

Comment: No it is not possible in zend framework.by the way how do you use your breakpoint ?

Comment: Set it up properly and then try it again. You don't go from the indexAction to the layout.phtml with the code you have presented. I'm kinda surprised it didn't throw an exception. Or maybe it did...

Comment: @RockyFord - Exception? Why?

Comment: @Abadis - What do You mean "how do you use your breakpoint"? I just set it & run the debegger (XDebug). When i run it it stops at the (1) line, then when I clik "Resume" it stops there again!...

Comment: You are assigning a variable to the view object and the trying to access it from the layout object. While there are many ways that these two objects interact they are not the same. The code you have in layout.phtml should be in index.phtml and then layout.phtml would access the the index.phtml content in the placeholder `$this->layout()->content`

Comment: yeah, okay but $this->layout()->content would give me the content outputed by index.phtml while i would like to access a concrete variable named var_controller...